# Difference between case 1 vs case 2?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I've worked on this question, [Convert Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/).

At first
I didn't know what to be returned in the end, so I created another function within the given one to carry out the recursion

```
**case 1**

def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> TreeNode:
    def bst(num_list):
        # base_case
        if len(nums) < 2:
            return TreeNode(nums[-1])

        # recursive_case
        mid = len(nums) // 2

        node = TreeNode(nums[mid])

        node.left = bst(nums[:mid])
        node.right = bst(nums[mid + 1:])

    ans = bst(nums)
    return ans
```

but, it kept giving me 'time limit exceeded or maximum depth in recursion' as a result.

Then, as soon as I removed the inner 'bts' function and then just did the same recursion process the given function(sortedArrayToBST) itself, the error had gone just like magic...

```
**case 2**

def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> TreeNode:
    if not nums:
        return None
    
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return TreeNode(nums[-1])
        
        # recursive_case
    mid = len(nums) // 2
    
    node = TreeNode(nums[mid])
    
    node.left = self.sortedArrayToBST(nums[:mid])
    node.right = self.sortedArrayToBST(nums[mid + 1:])
        
    return node
```

However, having said that, I can't see what's different between the two codes. There must be a key difference between the two but can't work it out on my own.

Could you please enlighten me on what the difference is between case 1 and case 2 so what causes error in one but not in the other.

Answer (score 2):

In case 1, the length of the processed list does not decrease across recursive calls because, while the parameter of `bts` is `num_list`, `nums` is being processed in its body.  The error would disappear in case 1 if `num_list` is processed (instead of `nums`) in `bts`.

Comment: Does stack overflow feature a thumbs-up stuff? got it. crystal clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Soo You can do two things: 1) up vote an answer and 2) as the poster of the question, you can accept an answer if it solves your issue.  So, you can do both in this case :)